# Issue with SQL Date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I am having issues with this code I am dealing with.

insert into movie
(movieid, title, genreid, releasedate, rating, movielength, directorid)
values
('1', 'Watchmen', '10',str_to_date('3/6/2009','%m-%d-%Y'), '4.4', '2h43m', '1021');

Anyone could give me advice for the incorrect datetime value error for "3/6/2009"?

Answer (score 1):

Your format has `-` but your data has `/`.